# Adding a prompt to UISearchBar breaks layout

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, uinavigationitem

I'm using an integrated UISearchBar with UINavigationItem:

```
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
```

It looks like this:
[image: normal layout]

However, when I add prompt to the UISearchBar, the layout breaks and the UI looks like this:

```
searchController.searchBar.prompt = "Adding text to the SearchBar"
```

[image: broken layout]

**What is the cause of this issue and how to resolve it?**

Comment: Could you supply the code for adding the addition `UILabel` to your `UISearchBar`

Comment: @RichAppz updated my question

Comment: Hi, add offset like this :- self.searchController.searchBar.searchFieldBackgroundPositionAdjustment = UIOffsetMake(0, 20);
Please tell me it works or not ? Thank You :)